# Change value of boundary of a multidimensional array

Tags: list-manipulation

How can we change the value of boundary of a multidimensional Array with arbitrary rank.
I tried to extract the indicies with:

```
dim = {8, 16, 32, 64};
rank = Length[dim];
arr = Array[Subscript[m, ##] &, dim];
allIndicies = CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{Table[1, rank], dim}];
idx = Select[Flatten[allIndicies, rank - 1], MemberQ[#, 1] || ContainsAny[# - dim, {0}] &];
```

But I wasn't able to find a way to use those indices to set a value on the border of my array:

```
arr[[idx]] = 0;
```

And I don't think my way to extract indicies is very efficient. I don't think this way is optimal anyway.

Comment: assuming `idx` is the correct list of indices, you can use `arr2=ReplacePart[arr,idx->0]` or `arr3 =MapAt[0&, arr, idx]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dim = {4, 5, 3, 2};
arr = Array[Subscript[m, ##] &, dim];
MatrixForm @ arr
```

[image]

```
borders = Join[#, RotateRight /@ #] &@Thread[{{1, -1}, All, {1, -1}, All}];

m1 = MapAt[ 0 &, arr, borders];
m2 = ReplacePart[ arr, (borders /. All -> Blank[]) -> 0];
m1 == m2
```

> True

```
MatrixForm @ m1
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `ArrayPad` on flattened `arr` and reshape using `Partition`:

```
m3 = Partition[ArrayPad[ArrayPad[ArrayFlatten[arr], -1], 1], dim[[3 ;;]]];
m1 == m2 == m3
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but perhaps you can use [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad):

```
array = Array[m, {3,3,3,3}];
ArrayPad[ArrayPad[array, -1], 1]//MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & m(2,2,2,2) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

or:

```
array = Array[m, {4,4,4,4}];
ArrayPad[ArrayPad[array, -1], 1]//MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & m(2,2,2,2) & m(2,2,2,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & m(2,2,3,2) & m(2,2,3,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & m(2,3,2,2) & m(2,3,2,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & m(2,3,3,2) & m(2,3,3,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & m(3,2,2,2) & m(3,2,2,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & m(3,2,3,2) & m(3,2,3,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & m(3,3,2,2) & m(3,3,2,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & m(3,3,3,2) & m(3,3,3,3) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$